# Understanding how preg_replace function works

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I saw a code like

```
<?php
$str = 'foo   112';
$str = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '2000', $str);
// This will be 'foo o' now
echo $str;
?>
```

Output comes like `foo 2000`. I am confused, as i was aware that [0-9]+ checks for number with in range and one or more. Should it not produce o/p like 200020002000?

Comment: no, because it matches ALL of the digits at once. `+` means "one or more". regexes are greedy by default.

Comment: The `+` quantifier matches an arbitrary length of whatever the charclass specifies. So it slurps all digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '+' in [0-9]+ will make it look for a string of numbers (with just one number being a string as well) and replace them with '2000'.

This expression would work as follows:

```
(...,$str)
```

^ Look at $str

```
'foo 112'

(..[0-9]..)
```

^ Search for number

```
'...1..' //Found one (literally)

(...]+..)
```

^ Check the next indexes to see if the match what you were just looking for

```
'...11..' //Still a number
'...112' //Still a number
```

Any more? Nope 
What did you end up with? '112'

```
(..., '2000',..)
```

^ Replace what you got with '2000'

```
Result: 'foo 2000'
```

*If it were just [0-9] it would work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

`'/[0-9]+/` will match all numerical values at the same time, `+` means one, or more occurrences, and then, `2000` means replace what `'/[0-9]+/` matched with `2000`.